# Which library should I use in hadoop 2.0?

Tags: hadoop, version

guys. I'm new to hadoop, and my hadoop version is 2.0.0-cdh4.0.1. But I'm confused about which library should I use. `mapred` or `mapreduce` or `mapreduce.lib`, `jobconf` or `job`, and so on.

I tried the examples of the 3rd education of *Hadoop: The Definitive Guide*, I got lots of warning. But when I tried the examples of 2ed education, it's much better. It totally confused me.

And when I tried to find some guide about hadoop, I can't finger out which version. It seems that the 2.0 version has some relationship about 0.2X? Is there some guide about hadoop 2.0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.0.1-alpha is the current version as per the API docs (Sept 2012) - http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/

From "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide" (3rd Ed.) - page 27 "Analyzing the Data with Hadoop"

"The new API is in the org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce package (and subpackages). The old API can still be found in org.apache.hadoop.mapred."

"Job control is performed through the Job class in the new API, rather than the old JobClient, which no longer exists in the new API."